# Resizing Auto Layout Constraint

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm developing an iOS application in Xcode 8. I'm having trouble getting my head around the auto-layout constraints even after reading various tutorials. I am trying to find what combination of constraints allows me to have an adjustable spacing between the top layout guide and the top of my image view.

Below is the preview of the view on iPhone 7 Plus:

---

iPhone 7 Plus Demo

[image: [1]]

The top constraint of the UIImageView is currently set to **=50**, which is the perfect size for larger screens. However, I am trying to have this spacing shrink on smaller screens, as seen below:

---

iPhone 4s Demo

[image: [2]]

I have tried what feels like all possible combinations of various constraints with different sizes and priorities but the spacing is either small on all screens or large on all screens. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different constraint for different trait.
You can do it like below

```
override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
    let trait = super.traitCollection
    if view.bounds.size.height < 500 {
        return UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact)
    }
    return trait
}
```

- Override trait collection
- Select constraint
- Select + button before constant field for the constraint in the inspector
- Select height as compact and width as any
- It will create another constant field for this constraint.
- Specify lower constant value

Else you can make that constraint an outlet and in code, check if view.bounds.size.height < some_value than use smaller value as constant for the constraint else regular value

Comment: This is new to me so thanks for opening my eyes to this. However, the height for the iPhone 7+ and 4s are both regular - so adding a variation for this effects both of them. I should have mentioned that I am only working in portrait mode - any ideas?

Comment: i made changes. You can override traitCollection in your view controller. You can make 4s devices height as compact always. This way you wont have to worry about orientation changes also

Comment: In case you want to change constraint constant value directly. You should do that with in updateViewConstraints() override. This way you wont have to relayout parent view after changing constraint

Comment: This looks like it will work, thanks. I will wait a little longer as ideally I would like to see the changes in the storyboard rather than just at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the top spacing proportional to the height by taking the outlet of the `topConstraint` and in the `viewDidLoad` method you can change its value. . Here you need to find a constant value which when multiplied with the actual height of the device gives the required top spacing. Say you need 50p in 7+ which has a screen size of 736p so the constant is 50/736 = 0.067. So in 4s the spacing can be 480 * 0.067 = 33.

You can do this like

```
topspace.constant = self.view.frame.size.height * 0.067
```

Comment: This would be my preferred choice as it would be visible in the storyboard. Unfortunately, when using your values I get the following: 

http://imgur.com/a/IrB94

If I use 50, it uses the same spacing on both screens rather than being adjustable.

Comment: I'm sorry what are you getting using the above values ??

Comment: Have you tried running using the above values on the device or simulator?

Comment: Yup in iOS if you give a constraint for an element it will be same throughout all the devices

Comment: Hmm OK, maybe what I am looking to achieve isn't possible.

Comment: I'm sorry what I gave as answer was to change the height proportional to the screen size. I will update the answer for the top constraint. I'm really sorry, but I don't believe you could achieve this using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around with the above ideas, I found a solution to my problem that lets me see the changes in the storyboard. I position my UIImageView in the preferred location (on iPhone 7+) and set an vertical alignment constraint at the current canvas value - I then set this constraint to have a priority of 750.

I then add a top constraint to the top layout guide which is greater than or equal to 10, this has a priority of 1000.

When seen on a larger screen, the UIImageView positions towards the vertical alignment. When seen on the smaller screens, the vertical alignment pushes the image to the top but the higher priority top constraint of 10 keeps it on the screen.